# Socket.io client plugin for firefox / Google chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Are there any Firefox / Google Chrome plugin for quickly testing [Socket.io](http://socket.io) server implementations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool

I built this tool for the same, its not a plugin but can used for the same purpose (even if it was a plugin, it would open up a new tab in the browser with the UI).

Advantages of making it available online is, the links can be shared among teams - teammates can directly click and use without filling any of the text fields.

[image: sokcet.io client tool]

For contributions, issues, feature request, please post via https://github.com/amritb/socketio-client-tool

Comment: wow very well done! this is great work thank you for sharing!

Comment: your tools is too good but only problem is that when ever i restart the server i have to refresh your link in browser.

Comment: @HimanshuPandey thanks - yes this is in our todo list :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a late reply but may help someone. I am using this App on my Mac Pro.

https://electronjs.org/apps/socket-io-tester

Comment: how send a file using this

Answer (score 2):

[Firecamp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp-a-campsite-for-d/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl), Here is the [website](https://firecamp.io).

Real-time programming is easy but too hard in terms of testing and debugging, This is the main reason I have built Firecamp, It's a visual testing dev tool for any **RealTime technology or platform** like *Socket.IO, WebSocket, Ably, Pusher* and lot more.

To test a SocketIO backend, you just need to follow 3 steps,

1. Connect server end-point
2. Add/Listen listeners
3. Emit emitter with a payload

Then you can save the whole configuration to use it in the future, save emitters payload and export/import for the mobility purpose would be very handy features for sharing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also created my own Chrome and Firefox extension. You can also run it from command line.
It is available here:
https://github.com/serajhqi/socketio-test-client

Firefox addon:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/socketio-client/

Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-test-client/ophmdkgfcjapomjdpfobjfbihojchbko

[image: sokcet.io test client]